# Is this possible to stay logged in my site even after the system goes off

Tags: php, cookies

I have a doubt regarding the remember me functionality.

Is it possible to stay logged in when the user open the site after the system goes off.

For example now I'm working on my site after login and suddenly the system goes off. And again opens my system, Is the system stay logged in with my username.

I searched for myself to store a remember me functionality to store cookies in my system. But I didn't get any clear solution for this. Anybody know how to write coding for this functionality. Could you help me to solve this remember me functionality issue

```
<?php 
include("classes.php");
$jeob = new EF_Sql();

    $email= $_POST['userid'];

    $password= $_POST['password1'];

    $papas=base64_encode($password);

    $check = $_POST['rememberme'];

        $tablename="user_record";

    $select_qry = $jeob->SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ".$jeob->dbprefix.$tablename." WHERE email ='$email' AND password ='$papas' AND active_link='1' ");

        if($jeob->SqlRows($select_qry) == "0"){                 

         echo "Invalid Username and Password";

        } else {

        if($check) {

setcookie("username", $email, time() + 3600);       // Sets the cookie username

        }

        $getuser = $jeob->SqlFetch($select_qry);

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $getuser['user_id'];  

        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = "normal";

        $_SESSION['email'] = $getuser['email'];     

        }
?>
```

The above coding is used in my site. But it stays logged in even after the browser close and again open the site. But it will be destroyed after the system gets shut down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies do not care if your system gets shut down or not.

There are a couple of things:

1. Your system is shut down longer than an hour. Your cookie is set to expire after an hour `setcookie("username", $email, time() + 3600);`. You could of course extend this to be weeks (or longer) if you want it to be "persistent".
2. You're using Internet Explorer and shut down without closing the browser "cleanly". Internet Explorer has a tendency to forget things after a "rough" shutdown.

There is however a security issue with your code in that just storing the username for an autologin is somewhat insecure. Anybody could simply create a 'username' cookie with the administrative email address in it, and be logged in as them. The way remember_me's are sometimes handled is to generate an 'autologin token', which will be an random hash, assigned against that user in the database, then stored in a cookie. This hash can expire every few days of no use or so to be able to stop seriously old logins from happening, or hijacking.

Comment: The cookies get cleared even after a few mins after created if I shut down my system. I am using chrome browser for checking this.

Comment: @Rithu Have you tried with other browsers? Perhaps it's a Chrome-specific issue...

Comment: Yes I tried also in IE and Firefox, the same issue continues. I spend the whole day for this one. But I cant get the solution and also a clear result for this one

Comment: @Rithu So, using the developer tools, you can see that the cookie is set and expires in an hour, you close browsers cleanly, restart, and come back, and the developer tools no longer show the cookie?

Answer (score 2):

Well i usually see people set a encrypted authentication cookie. If that cookie remains valid for 10 day's you can use that to authenticate the user, even if the session hase expired.

Answer (score 1):

**session / cookie**
make sure, you are actually using the cookie. Your snippet shows some `$_SESSION` stuff, but has no hint that the stored cookie is used.

**cookie expiriation**
The cookie gets only stored for one hour, see `time() + 3600`. 3600 stands for the seconds, how long your cookie will be valid. Maybe that is the problem. You can expend this time period to certain days or weeks, which is rather common.

**browser setting**
Also, it's possible that your browser has a strange cookie setting, so it deletes all cookies on closing. Maybe check with another browser.

Comment: Can't we store the cookies untill the next new logged in users

Comment: But when I close my system and again I open means it gets cleared in all browsers

Comment: check after the restart if the cookie is still stored. Most browsers allow this within the options. If so, the `$_SESSION` is not correctly reinitiated.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are the best solution to maintain the users session as they are stored in the browser. and every time the user sends an HTTP request the cookies are sent with the request.
your application can identify the user by reading the information in the cookie.

You may choose the age of your cookies according to your need.